# how to make a fixed header widht 100%

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i am using a fixed header in a bootstrap container and try to make the header a 100% width without margins and paddings. This is the structure of the html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="fixed-header" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="200">
    <!-- some content inside -->
    </div>
</div>
```

In my css:

```
.affix {
padding-left: 10px; 
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
z-index: 9999 !important;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);   
}
```

Image below is the result but i want the header against the left side of the screen, like the red arrow shows. How can i achieve that?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you using Bootstrap 4? There is no longer the Affix component that existed in Bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `position:fixed` or `position:absolute` and `left:0;`

without this codes:

```css
.fixed-header {
padding-left: 10px; 
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
z-index: 9999 !important;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);   
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="fixed-header" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="200">
    <!-- some content inside -->
    </div>
</div>
```

with `position:absolute` and `left:0;`

```css
.fixed-header {
  padding-left: 10px; 
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999 !important;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);   
  height:50px;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="fixed-header" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="200">
    <!-- some content inside -->
    </div>
</div>
```

see on full page.

Comment: you're welcome :) please accept the answer also. (Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.)

Answer (score -1):

```css
.fixed-header {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999 !important;
  background-color: red;   
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="fixed-header">
      test content
    </div>
</div>
```